# Pokemon Go is stuck on an old phone

Tags: pokemon-go

My old phone with Pokemon Go got screen cracked to the point it's impossible to use to sign out so I can't play on my new phone. So other than paying $100 to dollars to fix my old phone, what can I do?

Comment: As far as I am aware you can just log in on your new phone, without logging in out of your old phone? Or did you try that, and did not work?

Comment: Yeah I kept getting error messages. And I keep trying it at different times so it isn't the server acting up. Apparently they only want you on one phone too.

Comment: There are people who do evolve sessions on two phones at once, without errors (or being banned, but try at your own risk). I think it is something else. What do the error messages say?

Comment: Either "unable to authenticate" or it doesn't recognize my account at all. And I've uninstalled it over and over again.

Comment: Have you tried turning your phone off? I dunno if that will have any effect, but it might be worth a shot

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to sign out of your old device to log in on another one. Just sign in on the new phone.

If you still can't log in after resetting your password, contact niantic here: https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us

Comment: When I try signing on with the new phone it doesn't recognize my account (trying with the PTC account) but when I try to make a new account with it I get an error message. Same with the google account.

Comment: try resetting your password on ptc on the website?

Comment: Did that. And I know I have a PTC account with it.

Comment: and what happened?

Answer (score 2):

If your old phone is an android device you can use a mouse to control the screen, provided that the screen still displays an image.

Here is a video on how to do so:

You will need a small cable, it will need to be the same as the charger for the phone and female USB on the other end:

[Micro USB](https://www.amazon.co.uk/UGREEN-FBA_10396-Micro-Adapter-Cable-black/dp/B00LN3LQKQ/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1542025413&sr=8-4&keywords=micro%20usb%20to%20female%20usb)

Comment: To add to this, you could also use your phone as second display on your desktop through a similar kind of cable, put your actual display on duplicate and use your mouse that way.

Answer (score 1):

So long story short, I can access my account again. The account I have had since launch date. The secret to getting this sorted out is contacting support here: pokemon-go-support@nianticlabs.com

I was only able to find the email address by going to the app store.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how new you are to the game, you could also just create a new account as well. I know this isn't the most helpful option, but it is an option to consider. (The benefit of this, of course, is now that you know more, you can optimise your starting experience.)

Failing that, have you tried the 'forgotten password' (etc) features? If there's an option to select you've been hacked, such a feature tends to force a logout. If it's possible, you could also reset the broken phone to factory settings, which should wipe out your pokemon go app and data but without losing your account/pokemon/items.